# Configure BeagleBone as SPI slave using config-pin?

Tags: c, linux, beagleboneblack, spi, master-slave

Can I configure BeagleBone Black to be SPI slave using `config-pin` tool?
Currently, I can configure and use BBB as SPI master using this tool but couldn't find any documentation on how to configure BBB to be slave.

I knew from some posts that Linux started recently to support the slave side of SPI. But I couldn't find how!

Following is the output of `uname -a` command in BBB:

```
Linux beaglebone 4.9.82-ti-r102 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Feb 22 01:16:12 UTC 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Any help would be appreciated